# Limit of Complex Rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the following problem: $\\$
$\lim_{z \rightarrow i}\dfrac{z^2 + i}{z^4 - 1}$

I have tried everything I can think of to solve this problem (rationalizing, factoring, polar form, etc.). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I looked in the back of the book, because I believed it to be undefined, and it said that the answer is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: What are the respective limits of numerator and denominator?

Comment: Looks undefined to me since direct substitution gives $\dfrac{-1+i}0$.  In the single-variable (real) case this generally means the limit is undefined.  Pretty sure it's the same in the complex case (which is more or less a two-variable real case) but can't recall completely.

Comment: @tilper In complex analysis, one typically uses the Riemann sphere (aka the complex projective line), and then we have an unambiguous limit of $\infty$. At the beginning of the course, before the introduction of the Riemann sphere, it may be considered nonexistent, though.

Comment: Can we use L'Hospital Rule here?

Comment: @ Subhash Chand Bhoria  : it is not $$\dfrac00$$

Comment: The answer is supposedly $\frac {-1}{2}$